# Thunderbird stops receiving new e-mails

Tags: email, thunderbird, imap

First, my Thunderbird profile folder is around 17 GB, so I have got some mails there with multiple accounts (Exchange, GMail, all IMAP).

Two days ago when I was sending e-mails, it failed to move messages to the sent folder. I thought that this was just a temporary problem. Checking on the webmail it showed me that the mails were in the sent folder serverside, but not locally on my client.

Today I noticed that new e-mails are not incoming anymore. There is no error message shown, it just keeps loading and stops at some points.

For the reference:

- I tried the same credentials on Outlook and it worked as expected.
- There is enough disk space on the profile's disk (C:), more than 15 GB

I could not find other people with this problem yet. I do not really feel about killing my whole Thunderbird profile and setting up all accounts again - this could maybe solve this weird problem. But before doing that, is there anything else I could do?

Comment: Before that, you could attempt to archive. https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/archived-messages , getting all this understood and correct may take some time, but 17G when most of these e-mail servers do not allow large files is a lot. It could be applying archiving methods would be the thing to do regularly ?  If a database "breaks" it is not a fun thing to deal with it, fully seperated additional databases are some form of backup.

Comment: All mails are used with IMAP, so backing up is not really necessary. Your solution might even take longer than just setting up a new profile with Thunderbird...

Comment: Oh, well i have never really concidered other peoples computers a backup :-) But wouldnt it be kind also to them to archive this mass of stuff and remove it from the servers?

Comment: I think it is possible you could create the whole thing over again, load the mass back into the databases, and have it all break again.  by setting some of it aside, or using archiving methods it would never be that huge and unmanagable, then maybe it doesnt break anymore.